# Iterating to create objects in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to create many objects dynamically from a class I created:

```
class student(object):
   pass

myList=[x,y,z]

for obj in myList:
   obj=student()
```

Now this is the theory, BUT the interpreter gives me:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

So, how can to create numerous objects from my custom class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x, y, z` are treated as variables. Since they are not defined anywhere, you will get that `NameError` exception. To do what you want, you can initialize your list with `None`:

```
myList = [None, None, None]
```

Then, note that in:

```
for obj in myList:
    # some modification to obj
```

The elements in `myList` won't be modified, because `obj` gets a copy of the element in each iteartion. You can use *indexes* to access the elements of the list:

```
myList = [None, None, None]

for index in range(len(myList)):
    myList[index] = student()
```